# How to display an image tag with the ejs template engine for node js?

Tags: node.js, image, mongodb, ejs

Some background info: i am working with node.js with the express framework and with mongo and passport.js

So basically i was able to login to my app with the FB login and retrieve some info like username, token, id, displayName and photos. Then this data is saved in to my DB (mongo).

I can read all of the data out in my view with the ejs syntax except for the image.

in my view i have the following code for the image:

```
<%= user.facebook.profilePic %>
```

this returns the following output:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/Grace Yip/picture?type=large
```

but when i surf to this url in the browser i get the following error message

```
error: {
      message: "(#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: Grace      Yip",
      type: "OAuthException",
      code: 803
}
```

I tried putting the output of my data in an image tag like so:

```
<%= img_tag( user.facebook.profilePic ) %>
```

but then i get an error saying: Error: Failed to lookup view "error" in views directory "/Users/Grace/Desktop/QA/views".

When i remove the img_tag code the view works again.

Any idea how i can show the picture ... I am at a loss.

Thanks in advance!

Greetings,

Grace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to encode the URI by using the JavaScript in-built function [**`encodeURI`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI) because the URI contains a space in it which is making is invalid:

```
<%= img_tag(encodeURI(user.facebook.profilePic)) %>
```

Comment: Hi Chridam, i pasted the code you suggested in my view put it just returns the url not image ..

Comment: @GY22 Does that url contain any spaces? Will you get any error messages if you browse to that URL? If not and if it returns any data then simply wrap that in your image tag `<%= img_tag(encodeURI( user.facebook.profilePic)) %>`

Comment: No the url does not contain any spaces now. output is => https://graph.facebook.com/Grace%20Yip/picture?type=large. but when i surf to the url in the browser i get the error from above saying: error: {
      message: "(#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: Grace      Yip",
      type: "OAuthException",
      code: 803
}

Comment: @GY22 From that error message it clearly shows that the API doesn't recognise that alias `'Grace Yip'`. Are you sure that's the correct URI? Perhaps the value saved in mongodb is wrong?

Comment: Yes you were right. I wasn't pulling in the data right. Now i changed it to the id of the user and it works. Thanks for your help !!!

Answer (score 4):

i'm use 
user.facebook.profilepic is bson string path image http from graph facebook api with passport.js u can Try applying for bson str path

`<img src="<%= user.facebook.profilepic %>" alt="">` in .ejs file